# stop crontab getting filled by comments

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, cron-task

I have several tasks in my crontab, and lately after adding 2-3 cronjobs, my crontab is adding thoses extra comment lines. After a week the crontab was fill with more then 50 lines of comment like the ones below :

```
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.
# (/tmp/crontab.NcVinj installed on Tue May  5 07:34:18 2015)
# (Cronie version 4.2)
# (Cronie version 4.2)
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.
# (/var/tmp/cron installed on Mon Apr 13 09:03:58 2015)
# (Cronie version 4.2)
```

How can I make that stop?

script that might be causing the issue /home/clean_memory.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "" >/home/lilitime
if (/home/nxadmin/bin/cli ha | grep -q '172.16.1.1\s*Master')
then
crontab -l |sed -e 's=\(^.*/usr/local/nextone/bin/setdbrole.sh$\)=#\1=' | crontab -
echo Master commented on `date` >>/home/lilitime
sleep 1m
PID1=`ps -ef | grep slonik | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $2}'`
if [[ "" !=  "$PID1" ]]; then
kill -9 $PID1
fi
PID2=`ps -ef | grep setdbrole | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $2}'`
if [[ "" !=  "$PID2" ]]; then
kill -9 $PID2
fi
echo Master killed slon on `date` >>/home/lilitime
sleep 1m
/usr/bin/slon_kill; /usr/sbin/rcpostgresql stop
echo Master stopped sql on `date` >>/home/lilitime
sleep 1m
crontab -l | sed -e 's=^#\(.*/usr/local/nextone/bin/setdbrole.sh$\)=\1=' | crontab -
echo Master uncommented on `date` >>/home/lilitime
else
sleep 15m
crontab -l |sed -e 's=\(^.*/usr/local/nextone/bin/setdbrole.sh$\)=#\1=' | crontab -
echo Slave commented on `date` >>/home/lilitime
sleep 1m
PID1=`ps -ef | grep slonik | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $2}'`
if [[ "" !=  "$PID1" ]]; then
kill -9 $PID1
fi
PID2=`ps -ef | grep setdbrole | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $2}'`
if [[ "" !=  "$PID2" ]]; then
kill -9 $PID2
fi
echo Slave killed slon on `date` >>/home/lilitime
sleep 1m
/usr/bin/slon_kill; /usr/sbin/rcpostgresql stop
echo Slave stopped sql on `date` >>/home/lilitime
sleep 1m
crontab -l | sed -e 's=^#\(.*/usr/local/nextone/bin/setdbrole.sh$\)=\1=' | crontab -
echo Slave uncommented on `date` >>/home/lilitime
fi
```

Thanks

Comment: How do you edit your crontab? Do you use `crontab -e -u [user]` or do you edit the file `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/[user]`? The first is preferred (it also checks if your edits are correct upon exit).

Comment: used crontab -e and i was logged as root. Everything is working fine it just keep addind comment lines on every execute for some reason

Comment: What is your default editor? Do you *always* get these extra lines when you edit the crontab?

Comment: I use vi, and it is not when i edit the crontab, it is when the script is executed that they get added automaticly.

Comment: Which script do you mean exactly? The things you put inside crontab, or some other script?

Comment: `* * * * * /usr/local/nextone/bin/setdbrole.sh

0 5 * * * /bin/systemctl restart gb_subagent.service

30 11 * * * /home/clean_memory.sh &>/tmp/errorcron.log`


thoses are the scipts in my crontab and they are causing the problem apparantly

Comment: What's in `/home/clean_memory.sh` and `/usr/local/nextone/bin/setdbrole.sh`? If you need more space, you can edit your original question above.

Comment: thank you for the help wkoot, you can find my question above the /home/clean_memory.sh content. for the setbrole.sh it is not causing any issue because the problem started when i added the clean_memory.sh script.

Comment: Hmm, it's not really the way I'd do it, but it's not *really* wrong.. But you're skipping the "test if cron is ok" step because it's directly piping to crontab. Why do you have that `setdbrole.sh` script running? It seems to me like it would be safer to have a check to see if postgres is running inside the `setdbrole.sh` instead removing it from crontab in this cleanup script.

Comment: setbrole is running everyminute and basically when i am executing the script i do not want it to run for thoses minutes so i comment it and uncomment once i am finished. it is basically needed to run every minute but i am not certan what it does. do you think the `sed` command on crontab makes the crontab comment it self ?

Comment: Yes, the sed command will comment out the `setdbrole.sh` and then save the entire crontab. That's probably what's causing all those comment lines coming into your crontab. So that's why I'd suggest modifying the `setdbrole.sh` to *not run* when the `clean_memory.sh` script is running.